# Magento home page loading twice

Tags: magento-1.9

My home page of magento website is loading twice. I am not able to detect the reason. Could any one suggest me some idea? It is happing in live site only not local. i have checked below things.

```
<img src="">
<input type="image" src="">
<script src="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
<embed src="">
<object data="">
<iframe src="">
<video src="">
<video poster="">
<audio src="">
<command icon="">
<html manifest="">
<source src="">
```

It is not due to any of the above code

Comment: any caching server is there like cloudflare ??

Comment: Possibly if only happening in live then it seems some DB level. Check all settings of your Home CMS page in backend & compared with local.